# how to get all data which is posted by admin to all users

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get all tasks from all users who are authorised they can see all tasks of all user actually the problem is admin is in separate table and users are in separate table  because columns are different in admin and users and in my case admin will post the task and all authorised users can see tasks posted by admin following is the query where I want to modify

```
SELECT packages.id, packages.amount, packages.hours,packages.vehicle_type 
FROM  packages, vehicletypes 
WHERE  vehicletypes.userid = :userid AND packages.vehicle_type = vehicletypes.id
```

following is my admin, users and vehicle types table
[image: this is my admin table]

[image: this is my user table]
[image: this is vehicle types]
in above image all tasks are upload by admin from following query I am Abel to get user id

```
SELECT userid,  accesstokenexpiry
FROM adminsession
    INNER JOIN admin ON adminsession.userid = admin.id and accesstoken = :accesstoken

UNION ALL

SELECT userid,  accesstokenexpiry
FROM sessions 
    INNER JOIN users ON sessions.userid = users.id and accesstoken = :accesstokenusr'
```

Comment: Merge the 2 tables and have 1 table for all your users with a column to identify if they are Admin or User, then when another user type comes along, let say Manager for example, its a simple task to add a Manager, and you dont end up creating another table

Comment: its not possible because user and admin has different columns and different data types aswell

Comment: You can simply make some of the columns optional and only complete them for the relevant user type. Or, consider whether they actually _need_ to be different. A user is a user, surely? Just their roles are different. I don't know of any profesionally-made web application which has different tables just for different types of users, it's not a good approach.

Comment: You have also shown us a query that uses 2 tables you have made no reference to previously?

Comment: Even more reason to merge, as you kept a `userid` in the `vehicle` table, because you have 2 tables you have no idea if that userid is a Admin or a User. I realise this is probably what you were asking about, but to be honest it was not at all clear from your question as it stands

Comment: I understood all your points but I will explain it more clearly in admin table username and password is set to be not null but in users table I am login with only mobile number therefore I had kept username to null therefore if I merge both table I should keep username and password to not null if I keep it not null I will face problem in user registration

Comment: An Admin is just a user with more rights and privilages, if mobile number is your userid for users make it the same for an Admin.

Comment: you are right I can make it but this is my company requirement not mine hope you understand the situation

Comment: Just because the order came from a boss does not make it right :)

Comment: hmm is there any other way to do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248412/discussion-between-santosh-kumar-and-riggsfolly).

Answer (score 0):

after trying I found the solution if incase anyone faces the similar situation they can use following query

```
    SELECT packages.id, packages.amount, packages.hours,packages.vehicle_type 
from  packages, vehicletypes 
where  vehicletypes.userid = :userid 
or (select id from users where id = :userid2)   and packages.vehicle_type = vehicletypes.id
```